# My Preferences are not loading by default in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Every time i open my eclipse default preferences ( keys ) are not loading. 
but when open preferences-> keys then click on apply and close 
then able to use those shortcuts.
    I think that key preference file is not loading. 
    may i know how to make it load by default?
[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you're talking about. Can the issue be reproduced in Eclipse 2019-09 without any additional plug-ins installed? If yes, is there something in the log?

Comment: Yes it still exists in Eclipse 2019-09; 
added the image too

Comment: Can you give an example how to reproduce the issue? If you switch to a new workspace, does the issue remain?

Comment: open eclipse go to  preferences type keys change one of the short cut click apply changes close the eclipse now open the eclipse check was that short cut working ( it is not working ) now open again preferences type keys click apply and close 
now your short cut works

Comment: Is your keyboard broken or are you trying to say something with the missing typography? I have asked you for a concrete example to reproduce the issue because I cannot reproduce it. According to missing bug reports for this issue indicate it's just you. Therefore, be as specific as possible. In addition, I asked you if the issue is reproducible with a new workspace (because preferences are stored per workspace). Please answer these question by editing your question, not by adding comments. Is something enabled in _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preferences Synchronizer_?